# Google Data Studio Data credential issue

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am attempting to update the data credentials in my Google Data Studio report to my credentials versus viewer credentials. It says it updates but it never actually saves. Any idea on how to update the credentials so viewers without access to GBQ can view my report?

Answer (score 1):

Credentials are used by datastudio to access data from Bigquery when you configure the data source.

Once your report is connected to your data you can make it public and/or give view/edit access to certain users via google accounts. This is independent from Bigquery credentials as viewers of your report do not need access to your database.

You can set the visibility of your report to public, so anyone with the link can see it regardless of credentials:

1. Click on "share" on the upper right
2. Then "Manage access"
3. Then "Anyone with the link can view"
4. Click on "Save"
5. At this point anyone should be able to see your report by using its URL, you can test this by opening it in an incognito tab.

[Step by step screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwhAZ.jpg)

Hope this helps, and if not, please send more details.

Comment: i made the updates you suggested above and tried it in Incognito mode. It still did not load the data

Comment: Does the report functions correctly when you view it from your user? Can you provide screenshots from the issue and what your'e attempting to do? I'm assuming your data is is BigQuery, your report works fine when viewed from your google user, and the issue is when sharing the report for public use.